# Can Promise.all handle results as soon as possible, not waiting for all promises done

Tags: node.js, koa

I am using KOA2 to demo a bigpipe. I want to output a result as soon as possible when it's ready, rather than waiting until all results are ready(then output all).

I stuck here as code below: (`get_users` or `get_posts` return a promise)

```
async (ctx, next) => {

    ctx.res.write("<html><body>...")

    let data = await Promise.all( [res_fetch.get_users(), res_fetch.get_posts()] )

    ctx.res.write(data[0])
    ctx.res.write(data[1])
    ctx.res.write("</body></html>")
    ctx.res.end()
```

}

Ideally it should be something: (which I don't know how to achieve)

```
let data = await Promise.oneFinished( [res_fetch.get_users(), res_fetch.get_posts()] )

if (data[0] is finished)
    ctx.res.write(data[0])
else if (data[1] is finished)
    ctx.res.write(data[1])
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention: in koa2, seems I have to write `await` ahead of `promise`, otherwise the function will return immediately, rather than waiting for the promise getting resolved.

Comment: You can just put a `.then()` handler on each individual promise and respond there as soon as each individual result is ready and use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  let data = await
    Promise.all([
        res_fetch.get_users().then(result => {
            ctx.res.write(result)
        }),
        res_fetch.get_posts().then(result => {
            ctx.res.write(result)
        }),
    ])


    ctx.res.write("</body></html>")
    ctx.res.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), which returns the promise from the collection provided that resolves (or rejects) first!

```
let data = await Promise.race( [res_fetch.get_users(), res_fetch.get_posts()] )

if (data[0] is finished)
    ctx.res.write(data[0])
else if (data[1] is finished)
    ctx.res.write(data[1])
```